# NPM peer dependency conflict when there's no conflict

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js

Running `npm install` and getting this:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: site@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: next@13.5.0
npm ERR! node_modules/next
npm ERR!   next@"^13.5.6" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer next@"*" from next-sitemap@4.2.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/next-sitemap
npm ERR!     next-sitemap@"^4.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (@sentry/nextjs)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! next@"^13.5.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.2.0" from next@13.5.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/next
npm ERR!     next@"^13.5.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

For the life of me I don't understand where the conflict is. `next@"*"` matches `next@"^13.5.6"` and obviously `react@"^18.2.0"` matches `react@18.2.0`. What on Earth is going on?

Answer (score 0):

You installed version is 13.5.0, you should install 13.5.6

```
npm install next@13.5.6
```

If that does not help, remove lock.json and try again

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove this file from your project directory

```
package-lock.json
```

Then run the below command

```
npm install
```

it will work fine